# Selectable objects on UITableViewCell not responding to user input on iOS14

Tags: ios, ios14

While compiling a couple of projects with XCode 12 (beta 5 is the latest version at the moment) and running them on iOS14, I've noticed that `UIButton`, `UITextField`, and many other selectable objects are not responding to user input when inside of a `UITableViewCell`.

In some cases, it is possible to work around the issue by bringing the object to the front `(object.bringToFront())`, but this is not working for all the cases I'm facing. I've also noticed an empty view (layer) on top of the components of the cell when I use the "Debug View Hierarchy" Tool. This view is not present on XCode 11 builds. Is this some new cell configuration that I'm missing? Is there a standard way of disabling this behavior or will I have to be hacky to fix this?

PS: The issues were not present on the same projects when compiled with XCode 11 (or previous), even when running on iOS14.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All the select response issue may caused by adding subview on `UITableviewCell`. The right way is add on `UITableViewCell.contentView`, check it first.